# Selection of Radiobutton in android

Tags: android, radio-button, data-conversion

I am developing an application in which I have an activity in which there are three radiobuttons.
This is my .xml code...

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:hint="@string/hint"
        android:ems="10" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:gravity="center" >



         <RadioButton
             android:id="@+id/rad1"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
             android:text="@string/rad1" />

         <RadioButton
             android:id="@+id/rad2"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
             android:text="@string/rad2" />

          <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rad3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/rad3" 

            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp" />

    </RadioGroup>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I want to convert input of edittext in Text , Hexadecimal, Decimal format.
By default, it is Text value.
When user selects Hex radio button, then Text should be converted to Hex.
After that, when user selects Decimal, then Hex should be converted to Decimal...
My problem is how is it possible to convert in other two formats when user inputs in single format..
I have the logic of conversion...
please help me...thank you...

Comment: What is the issues here boy, Take the txt from edittext, on radio selection, U already have logic of conversation, Convert it and show again in same Edittext. What do u want from us?

Comment: but I have six different conversions of Three format...
Text to Dec, Text to Hex, Dec to Text, Dec to Hex, Hex to Dec, Hex to Text.
When user selects radio button then how these different functions know that from which format it has to convert on target format...

Comment: set some flag when converting.. Check condition of the flag while converting

Comment: as @Deepzz mention, use some flag and on CheckChange listener on radio button so u can convert on radio button check event.

Comment: can you give me one simple example???

Answer (score 0):

Its simple , just change the edit text input types on radio buttons onclicklisteners

```
          radio_bt_1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                  et_note_title.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);
                    }
        });





          radio_bt_2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                            et_note_title.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
                    }
        });
```

and change your imput types accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Here we go now...
At the end of day...
Finally

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private EditText et;
    private RadioGroup rg;
    int var=1 ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        rg = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
        //rg.check(R.id.rad1);



        rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup arg0, int arg1) {


                //D to T

                if(arg1==R.id.rad1)
                {
                    if(var==2)
                    {
                        char msg;
                        int num=0;
                        String str =et.getText().toString();
                        et.setText("");
                        String[] str1= str.split(" ");
                        String stringToAppend= "";

                        for(int i=0;i<str1.length;i++)
                        {
                             num=Integer.parseInt(str1[i]);
                             msg=(char) num;
                             String out = Character.toString(msg);
                             stringToAppend += out ;
                        }

                            et.setText(stringToAppend);
                          //  stringToAppend="";

                        var=1;

                    }

                    //H to T

                    if(var==3)
                    {
                        String string;
                        string = et.getText().toString();
                        et.setText("");
                        String[] str1=string.split(" ");
                        StringBuilder sb= new StringBuilder();
                        String strAppend="";
                        int a=0;
                        for(int i=0;i<str1.length;i++)
                        {
                            int hex = Integer.parseInt(str1[i], 16);
                            sb.append(hex + " ");

                        }

                        char msg;
                        int num=0;
                        String str =sb.toString();
                        String[] str2= str.split(" ");
                        String stringToAppend= "";

                        for(int i=0;i<str2.length;i++)
                        {
                             num=Integer.parseInt(str2[i]);
                             msg=(char) num;
                             String out = Character.toString(msg);
                             stringToAppend += out ;
                         }
                             et.setText(stringToAppend);

                        var=1;

                    }


                    //var=0;

                }

                if(arg1== R.id.rad2)
                {
                    // T to D
                    if(var==1)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            String myString=et.getText().toString();
                            et.setText("");
                            String stringToAppend ="";
                            for(char item : myString.toCharArray())
                            {
                                stringToAppend += ( (int)item) + " ";
                            }
                            et.setText(stringToAppend);
                             //stringToAppend="";
                             var=2;

                        }

                        catch(NumberFormatException e)
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }

                    if(var==3)
                    {
                        //H to D
                        String str;
                        str = et.getText().toString();
                        et.setText("");
                        String[] str1=str.split(" ");
                        StringBuilder sb= new StringBuilder();
                        String strAppend="";
                        int a=0;
                        for(int i=0;i<str1.length;i++)
                        {
                            int hex = Integer.parseInt(str1[i], 16);
                            sb.append(hex + " ");

                        }
                        et.setText("" + sb);
                        //sb.setLength(0);
                        var=2;

                    }


                }

                if(arg1==R.id.rad3)
                {
                    //T to H
                    if(var==1)
                    {
                        String str;
                        str = et.getText().toString();
                        et.setText("");
                        char[] chars = str.toCharArray();
                        StringBuffer strBuffer = new StringBuffer();
                        for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
                            strBuffer.append(Integer.toHexString((int) chars[i]) + " ");
                        }

                        et.setText("" + strBuffer + "");
                        //strBuffer.setLength(0);
                        var=3;

                    }

                    //D to H
                    if(var==2)
                    {
                        String str =et.getText().toString();
                        et.setText("");
                        String[] str1= str.split(" ");
                        String stringToAppend ="";
                        for(int i=0;i<str1.length;i++)
                        {
                            stringToAppend += Integer.toHexString(Integer.parseInt(str1[i])) + " ";
                        }

                        et.setText(stringToAppend);
                        // stringToAppend="";
                         var=3;
                    }


                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Complete Solution...